# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: todo

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a web framework by using Flask module. However, there is an error in my code that I couldn't solve it. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    task_content = request.form['content']
    new_task = Todo(content=task_content)

    try:
        db.session.add(new_task)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return 'There was an issue adding your task'
else:
    tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
    return render_template('index.html', tasks=tasks)

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    task_to_delete = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)

try:
    db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/')
except:
    return 'There was a problem deleting that task'

@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    task = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    task.content = request.form['content']

    try:
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except: 
        return 'There was an issue updating your task' 
else:
    return render_template('update.html', task=task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error shown for this code is

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: todo
```

My expected web framework is I can update and delete any task on the task column. My expected web framework is:

```
    Task        Added   Action
Wash dishes   2/8/2019  Delete
                        Update
```

For information, the action "Delete" and "Update" are an option to delete or update that particular task. Anyone can help me to solve this error? Thanks everyone.

Comment: you have to create table `todo` in file `test.db`. Flask doesn't create it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create table `todo` in file `test.db`

`Flask/SQLAlchemy` doesn't create it automatically so you have to use in code (after class `Todo`)

```
db.create_all()
```

But use it only once and later remove.

See [official documentation for flask_sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/)

Comment: Thanks furas, I am able to solve the problem by using this solution. Thanks.